# Why is my button only rotating every second click?

Tags: jquery, css, razor

I have a simple image I flip on top when it is clicked. I use jQuery to call the respond to clicks.

Now I am also hiding and showing elements which works every time, but the rotation only works on every second attempt, which means every fourth click.

Click one: rotate 180
Click two: rotate back.
Click three: no rotation
Click four: no rotation

it repeats then.

Why is this?

```js
let isRotated = false;

$(".buttonLayout").on("click", function() {
  var classTohide = ".classToHide";

  if (!isRotated) {
    $(classTohide).hide()
    isRotated = true
    $(this).toggleClass("rotate-180");
  } else {
    $(classTohide).show()
    isRotated = false
    $(this).toggleClass("rotate-180back");
  }
});
```

```css
.rotate-180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-180back {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" id="@position" class="buttonLayout" />
```

Comment: Where is your boolean `isRotated` set?

Comment: on top of the script element. so its part of the script but not part of the eventhandler as in my mind it should be...

Comment: Unless you're supporting IE8 [you don't need those vendor prefixes](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d). If you _are_ supporting IE8, you're a traitor to the cause. :P

Comment: Also, the [proper syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) is `transform: rotate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `toggleClass`, which removes the class, if the element has it and vice versa. So every second "round" of clicking, the class gets removed, when it should be added.

Change your code to this:

```js
let isRotated = false;

$(".buttonLayout").on("click", function() {
  if (!isRotated) {
    isRotated = true;

    //add one class and remove the other
    $(this).addClass("rotate-180");
    $(this).removeClass("rotate-180back");
  } else {
    isRotated = false;

    //add one class and remove the other
    $(this).addClass("rotate-180back");
    $(this).removeClass("rotate-180");
  }
});
```

```css
.rotate-180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate-180back {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" id="@position" class="buttonLayout" />
```

Comment: thank you very much. This was the issue! I also added "transition: transform 100ms;" to both the css classes to get an animation in rotation. it looks awesome now!